# How to show real-time output by running a PowerShell Script?

Tags: .net, vb.net, powershell

I am trying to run powershell script from VB and I want to see the output of the script as it is running inside a console application.  With my script (shown below) when I run from powershell it shows "Command Sleep Starting" and then waits for 5 seconds and then displays the other text.

However, when I run from VB.NET program, the execution waits for 5 seconds and dumps all the text output at once.  It doesn't execute first Write-Output command and then wait and then output as it should.

```
Write-Output "Command Sleeping Starting"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Output "Command ran successfully"
```

Any idea on how to show real-time execution output when I run the script from VB .Net Program?

Just for more info below is the code I used.

```
            Dim start As New ProcessStartInfo
            Dim ScriptsFolder As String = GetKeyValue("ScriptsFolder")
            Console.WriteLine(ScriptsFolder.ToString())
            start.FileName = "powershell.exe"
            start.Arguments = ScriptsFolder + "\" + ScriptFile
            start.UseShellExecute = False
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            start.RedirectStandardError = True

            Dim myproc As New Process
            myproc.StartInfo = start
            myproc.Start()
            Dim so As System.IO.StreamReader
            Dim se As System.IO.StreamReader
            se = myproc.StandardError
            so = myproc.StandardOutput
            myproc.WaitForExit()
            Console.WriteLine(so.ReadToEnd)
            Console.WriteLine(se.ReadToEnd)
```

Comment: [Someone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740118/interact-with-powershell-process-called-from-java-application/8740564#8740564) was trying to do this with Java. I'm not sure stdout can be read until the process exits..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered executing a PowerShell runspace programmatically using the System.Windows.Automation namespaces rather than starting the process?  You can then pass in a logger object to the pipeline and log to it, displaying the messages in realtime.

Here is a simple snippet for spinning up a Runspace in VB.NET

```
    ' create Powershell runspace 
    Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()

    ' open it 
    MyRunSpace.Open()

    ' create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
    Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()

    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)

    ' pass in a logger object you can use instead of Write-Output
    MyPipeline.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("logger", SomeLoggerObject) 

    ' execute the script 
    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()

    ' close the runspace 
    MyRunSpace.Close()
```

Comment: Agree with this. Instead of invoking PowerShell.exe, just use the API :-)

Comment: I do agree the above approach is the way to run powershell command but I am sorry that my question was not that.  I wanted to know if we could show incremental output as the script is running.  Will this approach show incremental output?

Comment: If you pass in a logger object to your script and then replace the write-output calls with calls to your logger, then the ability to show real-time data from your logger will depend on it's implementation.  An Example would be a TraceListener model where you could subscribe any listener you wish and visualize the logging output anyway you want.